# Joint origin vs Link origin

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. I was building a Xacro model for a robotic arm in Gazebo. I am confused about the origin tags of link and joint. What is the difference ? how can I determine the perfect values for both ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285055/joint-origin-vs-link-origin/) by [sezan92](https://answers.ros.org/users/29788/sezan92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2018-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should "play" with a simple urdf to see what's the difference.

It's all about the tf, with the origin tag of the joint you define where is the tf and with the origin of the link you define where your object is according to your tf. Here's an exemple :

The `joint` tag origin is `0 0 0` but the origin of the `link1` is `0 0 1`(and you can see the tfs are at the same position) :

[image: image description]

Here I set the `joint` tag origin to `0 0 1` and the origin of the `link1` is `0 0 0` :

[image: image description]

The link1 is at the same position in both case but the tf isn't. It comes in consideration when you have different type joints if you don't correctly define the tfs some rotations or translations could not behave as expected.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2